# Could not load NIB in bundle in custom view

Tags: ios

I created a custom `UIView` and has LoginView.h and LoginView.m and LoginView.xib

when I initialize it in a view controller it gaves me error.

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle`:

```
    -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        loginView=[[LoginView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width
                                                              , self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please give the rest of the error message. It's the important part.

Comment: In project -> Build Phases

Make sure the .xib is added to Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: it is in the bundle resources

Comment: Which version of Xcode that U use it ?

Comment: it is in the build phases.

Comment: the latest version. 4.6

Comment: So for file .xib, please check the Target Membership it  tick or not.

Comment: i checked the target too!

Answer (score 3):

I moved it to LoadDidView and it worked.